# How to use database method within broadcast sms reciever

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have a code that should import into a database when sms is received.
My problem is that i don't know how to call database method within the broadcast receiver class
I want to call something like this:
       `TouliosDB.eisagoghfititi(temaxismeno_sms[1],temaxismeno_sms[2],temaxismeno_sms[3],temaxismeno_sms[4]);`

where i got it like comment ! i know it's stupid and simple for some but im new to java, I'm using android studio 2.0

DatabaseHelper.java:

```
package toulios.ptixiakh.toulios;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

public static final String DATABASE_NAME="Toulios.db";
public static final String TABLE_NAME="Foitites_table";
public static final String Col_AM="AM";
public static final String Col_ONOMA="ONOMA";
public static final String Col_EPITHETO="EPITHETO";
public static final String Col_EXAMINO="EXAMINO";

public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
   // SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_NAME+"(AM INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,ONOMA TEXT,EPITHETO TEXT, EXAMINO INTEGER)");
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS"+TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate(db);
}
public boolean eisagoghfititi(String am,String onoma,String epitheto,String examino)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(Col_AM,am);
    contentValues.put(Col_ONOMA,onoma);
    contentValues.put(Col_EPITHETO,epitheto);
    contentValues.put(Col_EXAMINO,examino);
    long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME,null,contentValues);
    if(result == -1)
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}
}
```

IncomingSMSReceiver.java

```
package toulios.ptixiakh.toulios;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.HandlerThread;
import android.telephony.SmsManager;
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class  IncomingSMSReceiver extends  BroadcastReceiver{

private static final String SMS_RECEIVED ="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";

@Override
public void onReceive(Context _context, Intent _intent) {

    if (_intent.getAction().equals(SMS_RECEIVED)) {
        Bundle bundle = _intent.getExtras();
        if (bundle != null) {

            Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");

            SmsMessage[] messages = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < pdus.length; i++)
                messages[i] = SmsMessage
                        .createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
            for (SmsMessage message : messages) {
                String strPhoneNo = message.getOriginatingAddress();
                String msg = message.getMessageBody();
                if (msg.startsWith("02"))
                {
                    Toast.makeText(_context, "Whats up!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                if (msg.startsWith("01")){
                     try {
                        final String[] temaxismeno_sms = msg.split(":");

//TouliosDB.eisagoghfititi(temaxismeno_sms[1],temaxismeno_sms[2],temaxismeno_sms[3],temaxismeno_sms[4]);

                                     }
                                 });
                             }
                         }
                        Toast.makeText(_context, "Egine eisagwgh fititi!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        String message1 = "H Eisagwgh egine sthn vash.";// minima pou tha stalthei
                        SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
                        sms.sendTextMessage(strPhoneNo, null, message1, null, null);
                        Toast.makeText(_context, "O fititis idopiithike", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    catch (Exception e)
                        {
                        Toast.makeText(_context, "SMS failed, please try again.",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        }
            }}
        }
    }
}
}
```

sms_server.java

```
package toulios.ptixiakh.toulios;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;

public class sms_server extends AppCompatActivity {
DatabaseHelper TouliosDB=new DatabaseHelper(this);
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sms_server);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    TouliosDB = new DatabaseHelper(this);
    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton)     findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action",   Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_sms_server, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

Comment: You need to create DatabaseHelper Object in IncomingSMSReceiver in onRecieve method not in Activity.

Comment: can you tell me what to replace ?

Comment: Replace this TouliosDB.eisagoghfititi(temaxismeno_sms[1],temaxismeno_sms[2],temaxismeno_sms[3],temaxismeno_sms[4]);

with following.

DatabaseHelper TouliosDB = new DatabaseHelper(this);
TouliosDB.eisagoghfititi(temaxismeno_sms[1],temaxismeno_sms[2],temaxismeno_sms[3],temaxismeno_sms[4]);

in IncomingSMSReceiver Class.

Comment: i get one error " DatabaseHelper (android.content.Context) in DatabaseHelper can not be applied to (toulios.ptixiakh.toulios.IncomingSMSReceiver)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really understand your problem. Just call your method from your class DatabaseHelper. Replace `TouliosDB.eisagoghfititi(temaxismeno_sms[1],temaxismeno_sms[2],temaxismeno_sms[3],temaxismeno_sms[4]);`

with

```
DatabseHelper dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context.getApplicationContext());
```

`dbHelper.eisagoghfititi(temaxismeno_sms[1],temaxismeno_sms[2],temaxismeno_sms[3],temaxismeno_sms[4]);`

Comment: i get error  No static method eisagoghfititi(blabla) can not be refered from static contex

Comment: i get one error " DatabaseHelper (android.content.Context) in DatabaseHelper can not be applied to (toulios.ptixiakh.toulios.IncomingSMSReceiver)"

Comment: Edited again. You need to pass the application context